# Uninstall Visual Studio 2010 while keeping 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to make some room on my drive, and to uninstall Visual Studio 2010.

I don't use it anymore because I have the 2012, and I'd obviously like to keep using 2012, that is, is it safe to completely delete an older version of VS?

Will my 2012 continue to work straight after this uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> If you uninstall a version of Visual Studio on a computer that has
>   more than one version installed, the file associations for Visual
>   Studio are removed for all versions. You can remap these file
>   associations by using the Restore File Associations button on the
>   Environment, General page of the Options dialog box

Other than this maybe nothing changes, but its for you to find out. Of all the softwares Im generally happy with the install/uninstall system of VS, because of its predictability and documentation.

Comment: I've read this, so this is likely to be the only inconvenience ?

Comment: Well seems like it, I would rather have a Windows expert confirm here. But from what I know/have read/experienced, this seems to be it